# Vespa Text search tutorial: app.feed_df() not feeding data into the endpoint

Tags: jupyter-notebook, vespa

Im trying out the text search tutorial with pyvespa. Ive followed the tutorial to the T, but am having issues with the data feeder. I have no idea why it is not uploading any docs in the batches as you can see in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zvBL.png). Has anyone else encountered this or knows how to fix this? thanks so much!

oh here is the link to the tutorial I am following: https://pyvespa.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started-pyvespa.html

Answer (score 1):

https://pyvespa.readthedocs.io/en/latest/troubleshooting.html has some trings to try - the most common issue is not enough memory (min 4G for Docker) or disk space. Note that Vespa requires the available disk to be max 80% full.

The vespa.log file is available at `docker exec vespa vespa-logfmt`.